# Why doesn't unary addition work in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Why doesn't the += unary operator append model data in the following code?

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div   ng-controller="con1">
    <input ng-model="mydata"/>
    <br/>
    {{ mydata }}
</div>
</div>
```

angular:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("con1", function($scope) {
    $scope.mydata += $scope.mydata;
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/e41rzu9c/1/

The output I'm expecting this:

```
type into text box: h
output: h
type into text box: e
output: hhe
type into text box: l
output: hhehhel
type into text box: l
output: hhehhelhhehhell
```

In other words, it should concatenate the input against the previous input?

[Update: NaN issue is resolved per Davin Tyron's answer]
Also, how do I initialize the model so NaN doesn't display?  I tried adding ng-init="" to the input field but that had no effect.

Comment: The code is looking fine, can you please elaborate where are you using this code?

Comment: didn't you see the jsfiddle?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Are you expecting something to happen each time you type in the textbox?

Comment: I've updated the question with expected output.  I'm expecting the input to concatenate on the previous input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You risk getting in to an infinite loop due to 2 way data binding. Since behind the scenes, Angular wants to update the model when the field changes and the field when the model changes. There has to be something to break the cycle for it to work. Try this:

html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div   ng-controller="con1">
        <input ng-model="inputVal" ng-change="updateField()" />
        <br/>
        {{ mydata }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("con1", function($scope) {
    $scope.inputVal = '';
    $scope.mydata = '';
    $scope.updateField = function() {
        $scope.mydata += $scope.inputVal;
    };
});
```

Now the variable that you update will not be bound to the place you type, so it will only update when you actually type, not when the value changes.